# How exactly does React process arrays embedded in JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, jsx, render

Let's say you have an array called `items` in a React component `render()` method, like so:

```
const items = this.state.toDoList.map((item) => (<li>{item}</li>));
```

and in your component's render() method you return something like:

```
return (
  <div>
    <h1>My "To Do" List:</h1>
    <ul>{items}</ul>
  </div>
);
```

How exactly does React process the `{items}` syntax for rendering? I am asking because my understanding is that `{items}` evaluates to a JavaScript array, not JSX. Does React do something like apply the spread operator (`...`) when transpiling that code?

Even if you have something simpler like:

```
const test = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

and return:

```
return (<p>{test}</p>);
```

It appears the array elements are displayed, even though they themselves are not JSX. So what exactly does React do when it sees arrays wrapped in {} in JSX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am asking because my understanding is that {items} evaluates to a JavaScript array, not JSX.

React never even sees the JSX. JSX is convient syntax, but when you compile your code it becomes plain javascript with a bunch of calls to a function named `createElement`. The objects created by that function are what react interacts with.

For example, this:

```
<div>Hello World</div>
```

... gets transpiled to roughly this:

```
import { createElement } from 'react';

createElement('div', { children: "Hello World })
```

... and when that executes it makes an object that looks roughly like this:

```
{
  type: 'div',
  props: { children: "Hello World" }
}
```

This object is the instructions which tell react what to put on the page. In my example, the children is a string, but arrays are also supported. When you do this:

```
<ul>{items}</ul>
```

... you're creating a more deeply nested object. First you created the `items` array that looks like this:

```
[
  { type: 'li', props: /*...*/ },
  { type: 'li', props: /*...*/ },
  { type: 'li', props: /*...*/ },
  // etc
]
```

... and then you called `createElement('ul', { children: items })` resulting in this:

```
{
  type: 'ul',
  props: {
    children: [
      { type: 'li', props: /*...*/ },
      { type: 'li', props: /*...*/ },
      { type: 'li', props: /*...*/ },
      // etc
    ]
  }
}
```

When react sees that `children` is an array it knows that means you want to have multiple children. React will then recursively repeat its render process for each child.

Comment: Nicholas Tower, thank you for the explanation. I have some follow up questions if that's ok:

1. In your Hello World example, if you instead had something like

`<div><p>Hello</p><p> World</p></div>`

would that result in something like:

`{
  type: 'div',
  props: {
    children: [
      { type: 'p', props: { children: "Hello"}},
      { type: 'p', props: { children: " World"} },
      //etc
    ]
  }
}`

Basically if you have a JSX element that has multiple child elements, that would result in an object with a `props.children` set to an array?

Comment: 2. I read that "In React, when you attempt to render an array directly within JSX, React will concatenate the elements of the array into a single string and render that string". Does this sound correct?

Comment: 1) Yes, that will result in an array of children 2) Do you mean an array of strings like your final example? Technically, it will result in multiple text nodes being added to the DOM, but in practice, this looks to the user like one concatenated string. So yes, it's fair to say the strings are concatenated.

Comment: Good point, the example I was looking at that stated 2) was an array of strings like in my final example. Thank you for your explanations.